# Any ideas for "slow parent" alternative in new depsgraph?

Tags: scripting, parent

Alright, so I noticed that slow parenting doesn't work in new depsgraph

And I really need something like slow parenting to create a trailing/delay kind of motion for a bendy bone

Do you guys know any alternative? I saw something simillar by using driver with scripted expression that utilizes frames to calculate this type of thing

Thanks in advance!

ps: I'm using Blender v2.79.6
[image]